# Custom template use event expresso plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, events, plugins

client using event expresso 3 to build an table to display list of the class they provide. but I need to create custom template instead the default one.

I look into their documentation, taking me really long time to understand, I have couple tried, but not able to make it work.

**1. Location is not pulling**

`<?php $event_location = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_location', true); ?>
<div class="location">
  <h5<?php echo $event_location; ?></h5>

</div>`

**2. I keep getting error from this line also. 
error: undefined : $image_url['event_thumbnail_url']**

`<?php if ($image_url['event_thumbnail_url']) { ?>
       <img id="" class="" src="<?php echo 
       $image_url['event_thumbnail_url']; ?>" <?php } ?>`

My client purchased the plugin, so I don't have access to their support forum